# How to repeat html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Please read fully before answering (thank you):

I am wanting to seamlessly repeat a track (say 10secs) a given number of times (say 3 times) smoothly by:

1. *Extracting the audio from a given audio player* - not required, loaded a .wav from a server etc is fine
2. Concatenating the audio n times (adding the track onto the end of itself)
3. Playing the result in a new player

How could 2 be done? An example would be great but 2 is the most puzzling.

*Note:* Setting the original player to repeat itself etc is not an option as it's not smooth on most browsers.

Comment: Could you play the sound in javascript, or does is have to be in an HTML audio element?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 Whilst possible, it leads to a noticeable click in the audio due to the slight lag between the track finishing playing and the Javascript restarting it

Comment: AFAIK you can't access html5 `audio` tag raw data. You can get binary blob via ajax and use [Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/), but it still very, **very** experimental. In time when I investigated this API it was supported only in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Yes true, for now I am happy with very experimental - I just want to get to a demo in a browser. P.s. That's a good article, thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing using the `loop` attribute (and using JS to remove it after it's played through x times) doesn't work for you?

Comment: I would suggest using something like node.js, where merging streams is rather easy, as opposed to trying to figure out a technology (Audio API) that is so new it's not even guaranteed it will work the same from one Chrome version to another.

Comment: Whilst you are right, I am very keen to work with the experimental stuff as server side stuff is what I'm avoiding (too much load).

Answer (score 4):

The loop attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the audio will start over again, every time it is finished.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_loop

Answer (score 1):

a dirty solution that does work for this problem is to set an interval:

```
var sound = new Audio(document.getElementById("audio").src)
var trackLength = 5000 // 5 seconds for instance
var playthroughs = 3 //play through the file 3 times

var player = setInterval(function(){
    if(playthroughs > 0){
        sound.play();
        playthroughs--;
    }
    else clearInterval(player)
}, trackLength);
```

EDIT:
After someone pointed out to me my code could use a little improvement, i kinda got carried away a little. Here's the result:

```
var Sound = {
  que: {
    items: [],

    add: function(name){
      if(Sound.lib.items[name]) return Sound.que.items.push(Sound.lib.items[name]) - 1;
    },

    remove: function(key){
      Sound.que.items.splice(key, 1);
    },

    clear: function(){
      Sound.que.items = [];
    },

    play: function(startTrack){
      var playing = startTrack -1 || 0;


      var playNext = function(key){
        if(Sound.que.items[key]){
          if(Sound.que.items[key].isLoaded){
            var trackLength = Math.floor(Sound.que.items[playing].duration * 1000);

            Sound.que.items[key].play();

            var play = setTimeout(function(){
              playing++
              playNext(key +1)
            }, trackLength)
          }
          else{
            Sound.que.items[key].addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){
              playNext(key);
          })
        }

        }
      }

      playNext(playing);
    }
  },
  lib: {
    items: {},

    add: function(src, name){
      var obj = new Audio(src);
          obj.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){
            this.isLoaded = true;
          })
      if(!name){
        var key = 0;
        for(i in Sound.lib.items){
          key++;
        }
        name = key;
      }

      Sound.lib.items[name] = obj;
    },

    remove: function(name){
      if(typeof name == "string"){
        delete Sound.lib.items[name];
      }
    }
  },
}
```

an object oriented approach to this. it has a simple library of sounds and a que to which the sounds can be added in any order. i dont know if its fully debugged, but it seems to work nicely.

To add a new audio file to the library:

```
Sound.lib.add('path/to/file.mp3', 'trackName'); //trackname will be numerical if none is given.
```

To add an audio file to the que:

```
Sound.que.add('trackName');
```

To play the que:

```
Sound.que.play(2); // 2 indicates to start playing at the second sound in the que, assuming the que has 2 or more sounds in it.
```

To clear the que:

```
Sound.que.clear()
```

There's some more functionality in there, like clearing the que, removing items from the que and/or library. But it shouldnt be all that hard to figure out.

Comment: a slight improvement would be to add an `else clearInterval(player);`

Comment: i found this rather fun to code, so i created a repository. my first actually. [link](https://github.com/KevinKuyl/Sound.js) I'll try to get to it every now and then to make improvements.

Answer (score 1):

O_o This question is old why did StackOverflow show me this.

Well a simple way to do this is to listen on ended an start playing again.

```js
function play(audio, times, ended) {
    if (times <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    var played = 0;
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        played++;
        if (played < times) {            
            audio.play();
        } else if (ended) {
            ended();
        }
    });
    audio.play();
}

var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
play(audio, 3, function() {
    var sound = new Audio("http://www.soundjay.com/button/button-1.mp3");
    play(sound, 2);
});
```

```html
<audio src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is using [Web Audio API (spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API). This is however a standard that is in development, and therefore not finalised.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct answer to the question, but to play an HTML5 audio indefinitely you can do as follow:

```
const audio = new Audio('url_here.mp3');
audio.loop = true;
audio.play();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the most seamless way to do it is in Javascript

```
var sound=new Audio(document.getElementById("audio").src);
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
   sound.play();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid `sound.play();` isn't synchronous - so this just plays the sound once.