# Play sound a set number of times with JS player in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have the sound played 3 times and then stopped in my html page, it keeps looping if I enable loop to true or plays 1x if it's false.

My code looks like this at the moment, can someone advise?

```
var popupAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('popup_sound');
scene.on("enter", function (event) {
    popupAudioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    popupAudioPlayer.loop = true;
    popupAudioPlayer.playthroughs = 3;
    popupAudioPlayer.play()
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat html5 audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522929/how-to-repeat-html5-audio)

Answer (score 1):

The html `audio` element does not provide any attribute to determine the number of times it should play the audio.

One way to solve it is by using a counter and attaching an event listener to the `ended` event of the html `audio` element. Every time the play finishes the event listener will be executed, where you can decrement the counter and play the audio again.

Once the counter reaches 0, you remove the event listener.

Like this:

```js
var popupAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('popup_sound');
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');

scene.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    let counter = 3;
    
    const customPlay = function() {      
      popupAudioPlayer.play();
      counter--;
      
      if (counter === 0) {
        popupAudioPlayer.removeEventListener('ended', customPlay);
      }
    };
    
    popupAudioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', customPlay);
    
    popupAudioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    popupAudioPlayer.loop = false;    
    customPlay();
});
```

```html
<button id="scene">
  Play me 3 times
</button>

<audio 
  id="popup_sound"
  src="https://www.soundeffectsplus.com/uploads/prod_audio/41802331_bow-arrow-hit-target-01.mp3" />
```